# How to draw arrows across panels of multi-panel plot?

Tags: r

Suppose we have a multi-panel plot in R, created by using `layout()`. I would like to draw an arrow from a specified point in one panel to a specified point in *another* panel. Thus, the arrow goes across panels of the layout. The starting point of the arrow is specified in the coordinates of its panel, and the end point of the arrow is specified in the coordinates of the destination panel.

As a minimal example, consider this:

```
layout( matrix( 1:2 , nrow=2 ) )
plot( x=c(1,2) , y=c(1,2) , main="Plot 1" )
plot( x=c(10,20) , y=c(10,20) , main="Plot 2" )
# I want to make an arrow 
# from point c(x=1.2,y=1.2) in Plot 1 
# to point c(x=18,y=18) in Plot 2
```

I've searched for methods to accomplish this, but haven't found anything. Thank you for solutions or pointers.

Comment: I guess you can't, but you can draw both graphs in one layout, with the third graph which is the arrow, set opacity if you want to achieve good results: check this https://www.r-bloggers.com/overlapping-histogram-in-r/

Comment: @Cath: I have added a minimal example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update

*(I'm keeping the previous answer below this, but this more-programmatic way is better given your comments.)*

The trick is knowing how to convert from "user" coordinates to the coordinates of the overarching device. This can be done with `grconvertX` and `*Y`. I've made some sloppy helper functions here, though they are barely necessary.

```
user2ndc <- function(x, y) {
  list(x = grconvertX(x, 'user', 'ndc'),
       y = grconvertY(y, 'user', 'ndc'))
}
ndc2user <- function(x, y) {
  list(x = grconvertX(x, 'ndc', 'user'),
       y = grconvertY(y, 'ndc', 'user'))
}
```

For the sake of keeping magic-constants out of the code, I'll predefine your points-of-interest:

```
pointfrom <- list(x = 1.2, y = 1.2)
pointto <- list(x = 18, y = 18)
```

It's important that the conversion from `'user'` to `'ndc'` happen while the plot is still current; once you switch from plot 1 to 2, the coordinates change.

```
layout( matrix( 1:2 , nrow=2 ) )
```

Plot 1.

```
plot( x=c(1,2) , y=c(1,2) , main="Plot 1" )
points(y~x, data=pointfrom, pch=16, col='red')
ndcfrom <- with(pointfrom, user2ndc(x, y))
```

Plot 2.

```
plot( x=c(10,20) , y=c(10,20) , main="Plot 2" )
points(y~x, data=pointto, pch=16, col='red')
ndcto <- with(pointto, user2ndc(x, y))
```

As I did before (far below here), I remap the region on which the next plotting commands will take place. Under the hood, `layout` is doing things like this. (Some neat tricks can be done with `par(fig=..., new=T)`, including overlaying one plot in, around, or barely-overlapping another.)

```
par(fig=c(0:1,0:1), new=TRUE)
plot.new()
newpoints <- ndc2user(c(ndcfrom$x, ndcto$x), c(ndcfrom$y, ndcto$y))
with(newpoints, arrows(x[1], y[1], x[2], y[2], col='green', lwd=2))
```

I might have been able to avoid the `ndc2user` conversino from `ndc` back to current user points, but that's playing with margins and axis-expansion and things like that, so I opted not to.

It is possible that the translated points may be outside of the user-points region of this last overlaid plot, in which case they may be masked. To fix this, add `xpd=NA` to `arrows` (or in a `par(xpd=NA)` before it).

[image]

---

### Generalized

Okay, so imagine you want to be able to determine the coordinates of any drawing after `layout` completion. There's a more complex implementation that currently supports what you're asking for. the only requirement is that you call `NDC$add()` after every (meaningful) plot. For example:

```
NDC$reset()
layout(matrix(1:4, nrow=2))
plot(1)
NDC$add()
plot(11)
NDC$add()
plot(21)
NDC$add()
plot(31)
NDC$add()
with(NDC$convert(1:4, c(1,1,1,1), c(1,11,21,31)), {
  arrows(x[1], y[1], x[2], y[2], xpd=NA, col='red')
  arrows(x[2], y[2], x[3], y[3], xpd=NA, col='blue')
  arrows(x[3], y[3], x[4], y[4], xpd=NA, col='green')
})
```

Source can be found here: https://gist.github.com/r2evans/8a8ba8fff060bade13bf21e89f0616c5

[image]

---

### Previous Answer

One way is to use `par(fig=...,new=TRUE)`, but it does not preserve the coordinates you e

```
layout(matrix(1:4,nr=2))
plot(1)
plot(1)
plot(1)
plot(1)
par(fig=c(0,1,0,1),new=TRUE)
plot.new()
lines(c(0.25,0.75),c(0.25,0.75),col='blue',lwd=2)
```

[image]

Since you may be more likely to use this if you have better (non-arbitrary) control over the ends of the points, here's a trick to allow you more control over the points. If I use this, connectiong the top-left point with the bottom-right point:

```
p <- locator(2)
str(p)
# List of 2
#  $ x: num [1:2] 0.181 0.819
#  $ y: num [1:2] 0.9738 0.0265
```

and then in place of `lines` above I use this:

```
with(p, arrows(x[1], y[1], x[2], y[2], col='green', lwd=2))
```

I get

[image]

(This picture and the values in `p` demonstrate how the coordinates are different. When using `par(fig=...,new=T);plot.new();`, the coordinates return to

```
par('usr')
# [1] -0.04  1.04 -0.04  1.04
```

There might be trickery to try to workaround this (such as if you need to automate this step), but it likely will be non-trivial (and not robust).

Comment: Thanks for the clever suggestions! But I'd really like to be able to specify the start and end points using the coordinates of the start and end plots.

Comment: See the edited answer. In general, messing with "device" coordinates (as opposed to "user" coordinates) might be too-much in the internals, but it works well enough (and has for several years).

Comment: Fabulous! I didn't know about the `grconvertX()` function, nor `par(fig=...)`. I marked the answer as accepted. But I'm wondering, is there a way to specify *after* drawing all plots which panel within the layout is being referred to, so the to-from points can be specified *after* making all the panel plots?

Comment: John, see my new edit, with source code found [here](https://gist.github.com/r2evans/8a8ba8fff060bade13bf21e89f0616c5).

Comment: Brilliant. Many thanks for your extensive efforts on this. I hope many people will find this to be useful and will cite your work here!